# AG Grid module import error in Angular 8 using Ivy

Tags: ag-grid-angular, angular-ivy

I'm getting the following error when trying to import the ag grid module in an Angular 8 app using Ivy.

`ERROR in There is no format with import statements in 'path_to_node_modules/node_modules/ag-grid-angular' entry-point.`

The error goes away if i disable Ivy. Does anyone know a workaround?

Packages versions:

```
 "ag-grid-angular": "^21.0.0",
 "ag-grid-community": "^21.0.0",
 "ag-grid-enterprise": "^21.0.0",
```

Comment: hello, could you write me, i am about `agGridAngular.js:440 ag-Grid-angular: could not find EventEmitter: popupToFront` - i saw you had the same issue,
my email: roman13275@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an issue on the Angular CLI side - see this issue comment here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29564#issuecomment-486957461

In the meantime I believe you'll be able to get Ivy to work with ag-Grid (and other similar libraries) by using `@angular/compiler-cli@next`, instead of the latest Angular 8 release.

Comment: I've tried using @next and resulted in another error.

Comment: I can't recall it. I rolled back everything to 8.0.2 and disabled ivy.